# Cannot Connect Centos VM to The Internet (Bridge Connection)

Tags: centos, vmware

I just installed *Centos 6.10* on *Vmware Workstation 15* on *Windows 7* and cannot connect to the internet.

Typing command :

```
ping www.google.com
```

Would produced :

```
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

And if we call `ifconfig` command, the netwrok interface didn't show addresses of neither *inet (IPv4)* nor *inet6 (IPv6)*.

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally i solved this in a way:

1. First turn  *Centos VM* in the *Vmware* off.
2. In the *Vmware* go to **Edit -> Virtual Network Editor**.
3. Select **VMNet0** which is **Bridge** type.
4. Select **Bridge (Connect VMs directly to the external network)**.
5. In the dropdown menu of **Bridge to** (Default is automatic) choose your *Activated Network Adapter*.
6. Finally click **OK** Button.
7. Now turn your *Centos VM* on and then check for the connection.

To know your Activated Network Adapter (In Windows 7):

1. Right click the connection (on taskbar).
2. And click **Open Network and Sharing Center**.
3. Click **Change Adapter Setting**.
4. And you will see your *Netowrk Adapter*. For me the current *Activated Netowork Adapter* is *Qualcomm Atheros AR956x Wireless* Netowork Adapter.

Hope this help.

Thanks.